# How can I limit items in the cart with map function (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an issue that I cannot limit the items of the cart if the user added more 3 items.
I don't wanna change the state of the cart so I map the items and add the condition to it. But it does not work well. When the items are more than 3 it will not display the items. Which is not I expected. I only want the cart, not display more the items if cartNumber is more than 3. Can someone help me with this?

```
Example : let cartNumber = [{...},{...}]

{
  cartNumber !== undefined && cartNumber.length < 3
    ? cartNumber.map((item) => {
        return (
          <li className="clearfix">
            <img src={item.imgSrc} style={{ width: "30%" }} alt="item1" />
            <span className="item-name" style={{ verticalAlign: "middle" }}>
              {item.name}
            </span>
            <span className="item-price" style={{ verticalAlign: "middle" }}>
              {item.price} kr
            </span>
            <span className="item-quantity" style={{ verticalAlign: "middle" }}>
              Quantity: {item.quantity}
            </span>
          </li>
        );
      })
    : null;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
{
  cartNumber !== undefined &&
    cartNumber.slice(0, 3).map((item) => (
      <li className="clearfix">
        <img src={item.imgSrc} style={{ width: '30%' }} alt="item1" />
        <span className="item-name" style={{ verticalAlign: 'middle' }}>
          {item.name}
        </span>
        <span className="item-price" style={{ verticalAlign: 'middle' }}>
          {item.price} kr
        </span>
        <span className="item-quantity" style={{ verticalAlign: 'middle' }}>
          Quantity: {item.quantity}
        </span>
      </li>
    ));
}
```

I suggest you default that cartNumber as empty array. and just use `cartNumber.slice(0, 3).map...`

Comment: It worked. Awesome. You are so helpful. Thanks a lot